# passing dynamic value to eventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering why when i do this

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function() {

ajaxLeaveRoom(rid, uid, urlwr);

});
```

it works, but when i do this

```
var evsup = "unload"; 

window.addEventListener(evsup, function() {

ajaxLeaveRoom(rid, uid, urlwr);

});
```

it does not work!   is there a special way to pass that var to the Listener?

i need the dynamic var because im testing for unload or beforeunload in another function so i made a static var to test but it does not work...

thanks

here is the full code

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">

/* yes the literals are backwords thats how it works */
/* for smarty in js - see smarty forum */
/* addEventListener is ok we do not support < ie9 */
/* do not use function(event) it does not work on ie */

"use strict";

var r = '?ran='+Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) +1);
var ajaxurl = {/literal} '{$ajaxUrl}'{literal};
var rid  = {/literal} '{$room}' {literal};
var uid  = {/literal} '{$userid}' {literal};
var urlwr = ajaxurl+r; 


$( document ).ready(function() {

//var evsup = checkEventSupport();

//alert(sup);

var evsup = "unload"; /* or beforeunload */

alert(evsup);

});


window.addEventListener(evsup, function() {

ajaxLeaveRoom(rid, uid, urlwr);

});

</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: What you have should work fine. Are you sure `evsup` is in scope of where you use it in the event definition? Check the console for errors elsewhere in your code

Comment: It will work like you did. There must be other problems.

Comment: ReferenceError: evsup is not defined... wait i think i found it... that setting for evsup is inside my doc ready function i need to move it outside i bet

Comment: If `evsup` is undefined, it means that you are not defining it by the time the add event listener is called.

Comment: ok full code added

Comment: thanks yes i just had to move my close ready function to the end and wrap it... thanks so much :)